# use customer variable text in email

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, custom-variable

I know in email we can use `{{var customer.getMarketerName()}}` for get and use customer attribute.

But my attribute is an select and above code return id replace text 
how I can get attribute text?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get customer attribute label first in your code and then pass it to your email template.

```
$marketerName = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('marketer_name')->getFrontend()->getAttribute()->getFrontendLabel();
```

Then you can pass `$marketerName` in your email template variables.

Comment: thanks ... i should use 'var' for get attribute text and i can not use php code 
is there any way ?

Comment: You need to put this code where you are setting variables for your template.

Comment: sorry but i just access email templates... i know it is so fun but i could not use php code

Comment: Sorry but there is no way where you can get label from id in your HTML file.

Comment: how i can get label from id ??

Comment: To get label from ID you need to use php code.